# In yii, facebook opengraph return uid when user logout from facebook in another browser tab

Tags: php, yii, facebook-php-sdk, yii-extensions

I am working in yii 1.1 and have an extension yii-facebook-opengraph wrapper of php sdk 3.1.1

```
    $facebook_id = Yii::app()->facebook->getUser();
    if ($facebook_id) 
      { 
       // check that you get a Facebook ID before calling api()
       // now we know we have a Facebook Session,
       $user_info = Yii::app()->facebook->api('/me'); // so it's safe to call api()
       if ($user_info) 
       {
          // ...  code ...
       }
      }
```

the problem is when user login by facebook in one tab and logout from facebook in other tab then `$facebook_id` is still set. Why? 
and when tried to access user info, got error "Requires user session ".
i have searched a lot and find something like

```
$facebook->getSession();
```

to get user session but this function is not available in yii-facebook-opengraph
Please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($facebook_id) {
    try
    {
        $user_info = $fb->api('/me');
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        $fb->destroySession();
    }
}
```

Where *$fb* is your instance of your **$fb = new Facebook();**